# Finding max height/depth in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

After going through the basics of Binary Tree, I define it in C++ as below :

```
struct Node
{
    int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
}*left=NULL,*right=NULL;

int getDepth(Node* t)
{
  if (t == NULL)
    return 0;
  else
    {
      int lDepth = getDepth(t->left);
      int rDepth = getDepth(t->right);

      if (lDepth > rDepth)
        return(lDepth + 1);
      else 
        return(rDepth + 1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    // root
    Node* root = new Node();
    root->key = 1;
    
    // left subtree
    root->left = new Node();
    root->left->key = 2;
    root->left->left = new Node();
    root->left->left->key = 4;
    root->left->right = new Node();
    root->left->right->key = 5;
    
    // right subtree
    root->right = new Node();
    root->right->key = 3;
}
```

Now If I try to find maximum height/depth using this code, it returns 3 instead of 2. What may be the reason? Also, Why I didn't find this way of assigning value to nodes anywhere?

Edit: Adding requested code

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't show your algorithm for finding the depth - but I'm guessing you're counting the root node.

Comment: 1. You missed to add the code for calculating depth. 2. You missed to initialise child node pointers. `struct Node { /*... */ } *left = NULL, *right = NULL;` creates two global variables of type `Node*`. If you want to provide default values must look like this: `struct Node { Node* left = nullptr; Node* right = nullptr; };` (side note: `nullptr` is a C++ *keyword* you should prefer over old/obsolete C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: added full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

#### 1. You're incorrectly setting up the struct `Node`.

To define a type `Node` where the members have initial values, your syntax is slightly wrong. Instead, do:

```
struct Node {
    int key = 0;
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;
};
```

#### 2. The height of the tree is 3.

Here's a visual representation of the tree you've created. It has 3 levels.

```
         1
        / \
       2   3
      / \
     4   5
```

Comment: But [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-maximum-depth-or-height-of-a-tree/), height is 2

Comment: Depends how you count, that page says "Height of empty tree is 0", however your code has 0 for the "null" tree, 1 for a tree with just a root etc... You should change the null case in getDepth to return -1

Comment: @Rohit The link you provided is wrong. It *says* height is 2, but actually it is 3, there, too. The code provide there would calculate height as 3 as well. Additionally, once more an example of bad code on geeks for geeks (including bits/stdc++.h, `using namespace std`, inconsistent indentation style, `else` after `return`, ...).

Comment: That geeks for geeks article is ___absolutely terrible___.  Defining the height of an empty tree (with no nodes) to be `0` and defining the height of a tree with 1 node to **also** be `0` is mathematically awkward to say the least.  It prevents us from from using the function to calculate a node's height based on the height of its children subtrees because - because it __matters__ if there's 1 node there or no nodes there.  Very bad definition of height.  At least they should have said that a tree with no nodes has _undefined_ height.  Then you could represent that with (-1) or something.